# Shortcut for: | less [ENTER]

Tags: linux, shell, shortcut, keyboard-shortcuts

I often type `| less [ENTER]`.

I would like to optimize this.

Environment: Ubuntu 20.04

This needs to work for terminals running in the browser, too.

Any idea how I could enter above string with less effort?

It would be super cool, if the CapsLock key could be used for this, since I don't need this key (and it is easy to access with the ten finger touch-typing-system).

Comment: Get a keyboard with programmable keys (mine's a Corsair K95) - that's one option

Comment: @Chopper3 i am addicted to the trackpoint between G and H. I can't live without it. AFAIK there are no programmable keyboards with a trackpoint.

Comment: This question belongs to https://superuser.com 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `xdotool` : `sudo apt-get install xdotool`

- Go to : Keyboard settings
- Create a shortcut with :

`bash -c ' sleep 0.3; xdotool getactivewindow  type " | less" ; xdotool key Return '`

- Bind a key combinaison, for example : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

[Keyboard settings (sorry in french)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeoMb.png)

### To use caps lock key

Try this :

- Bind your <kbd>CAPSLOCK</kbd> to <kbd>SuperL</kbd> : `setxkbmap -option caps:super`, or an other useless key for you (be careful with keys conflicts).
- Map your command to your new key
  [image]

Comment: Is there a way to use the (otherwise useless) CapsLock key to trigger the xdotool shortcut? CapsLock "L" would be cool.

Comment: Yes, just trigger the CapsLock key when the prompt wait the key shorcut (tested on Ubuntu 20.04). But I think it's not a really good idea because your keyboard will be capslocked every time you trigger the shortcut, and you need to trigger again to revert capslock (and off course, your command will be resend again, could be a mess !).

Comment: I don't need CapsLock. It would be great if CapsLock could be used for several such cool shortcuts.

Comment: It can be tricky to deal with CAPS_LOCK key, but I have edited my answer with a trick (tested on Ubuntu 20.04, french keyboard).

Comment: why is "sleep" needed?

Comment: If you remove the `sleep` instruction, the behavior can be incorrect.

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use less my_file instead of piping to less ?
you could even just add an alias for less so you do not need to type less completly.

> alias l=less

Comment: I want to use the command less on stdout of a program, not in a file